# Insert data into columns of table in database using .tosql

Tags: python, sql, append

I know I can use

> if_exists = 'append'

But this will add data to the bottom of my table. I want to add it right next to it.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to achieve;  please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of the initial state, the exact code you run (preferably as a [mcve]), what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: "I want to add it right next to it". This is not clear. Do you want to update a row of data? Add columns to the table? This post needs far more information to receive a useful answer.